# ProgressDlgTitleInstalling string not visible when product already installed and rerun msi

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using the following .wxl file to customize two installation dialog screens.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="ProgressDlg_Title">My Progress Dlg Title</String>
  <String Id="ProgressDlgTitleInstalling">Installing My Product</String>
  <String Id="ExitDialog_Title">My Product Setup</String>

  <!--Failure Dialog Customization-->
  <String Id="FatalError_Title">My Fatal Error Title</String>
  <String Id="FatalErrorTitle">{\WixUI_Font_Bigger}My installation ended prematurely./String>
  <String Id="FatalErrorDescription1">My Product Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified. To install this program at a later time, run Setup Wizard again.</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

The problem I am having is that the ProgressDlgTitleInstalling string is not visible on subsequent runs of the msi.  It is visible the first time I run the msi, but then I rerun the msi and this string is not visible.

I have no idea how to debug this.  I used verbose logging and checked the msi log but found no clues on how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

ProgressDlgTitleInstalling is used only during initial install. Other operations use different strings: ProgressDlgTitleChanging, ProgressDlgTitleRepairing, ProgressDlgTitleRemoving, ProgressDlgTitleUpdating.

You can see this in the [WiX source code for the progress dialog](https://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/ProgressDlg.wxs).

Comment: I tried all of the different ProgressDlgTitle<option>s that are in the source code for the progress dialog, but it is still empty which makes me wonder.  Why is this title empty?  Shouldn't it get some default value at least?

Comment: How are you running the package when there's no text?

Comment: Double clicking the msi which is on the desktop.

Comment: Then which string is shown depends on the option you choose in the maintenance mode dialog.

Comment: Do you mean MainenanceTypeDlg<option>s in the wix source?  It seems to me that the default value should at least get displayed?

Comment: When you double-click an .msi that's already installed, you get options to change, repair, or remove. Those options control the text that's displayed during the install.